# Unable to run project in Android Studio. Maybe because of gradle?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I opened up a project in Android Studio and was unable to run it.

Not sure if this is the problem but there's a pop up that says the project

> "is not a gradle-based project"

even though when I check, there is a gradle build file.

The emulator seems to be working though nothing runs. I didn't create the folder, I got it from Programming Mobile Applications for Android Handheld Systems: Part 1.

I'm not sure which file I should be opening to even get it to run.

[image: Here]

I've seen people posting questions where they're using Eclipse. Am I supposed to be using that with a gradle plug-in to open it instead?

Comment: Try importing the project as Eclipse in Android studio then click those consecutive **next**sess.

Comment: Your project is not Gradle based. Where is the Gradle build file in your image?

Comment: I didn't take a screenshot of it but the build file was in the src folder, but I figured out why there was a problem running the file.

Answer (score 0):

- open android studio home screen

  select option Import project(EclipseADT,Gradle,etc)

  select your project location and click build button.then your eclipse
  project converting gradle base system and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why there was a problem. Somehow, I managed to nest the whole project inside of itself causing an infinite loop. When I looked through the logs again, the error log reported that there was a problem because it couldn't find the file. Now I have a problem deleting the whole file because the folders are nested too deep...

But anyway, I was able to create a new copy of the files and actually import it successfully this time. :) Thanks for all your help.